# Python - Merge two dictionaries into a single list (By Keys)

Tags: python

I have:

```
market = {
       "APPL" : 2.33 },
        "IBM" : 3.44 },
        "AMZN" : 5.33 }
}

portfolio = {
        "APPL" : 0.20,
        "IBM" : 0.05
}
```

I want to merge the above dictionaries into a single list, that has the following structure.  It uses common keys to do the multiplication:

```
index 0:  Multiplication of 2.33 and 0.20
index 1:  Multiplication of 3.44 and 0.05
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
market = {
       "APPL" : 2.33,
        "IBM" : 3.44,
        "AMZN" : 5.33 }

portfolio = {
        "APPL" : 0.20,
        "IBM" : 0.05
}

out = [value * market[key] for key, value in portfolio.items()]
print(out)

# [0.466, 0.17200000000000001]
```

Note, though, that dicts are only ordered since Python 3.6, so the order of the values in the list are only guaranteed to match the order of the items in the `portfolio` dict with these versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the items of portfolio like this:

```
[value * market[key] for key, value in portfolio.items()]
```

or, if you wanted to keep the keys:

```
{key: value * market[key] for key, value in portfolio.items()}
```

Edit: I missed that you wanted a list, not a dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension that iterates through the keys of `portfolio` and outputs products of the corresponding values:

```
[market[k] * v for k, v in portfolio.items()]
```